# Searching Pages Library using FullTextSqlQuery

Tags: search, sql, fulltextsqlquery, pages

Can anybody please point me in the right direction of searching the Pages library using FullTextSqlQuery? I've successfully instanced a new FullTextSqlQuery and have dealt with all of the necessary properties. It retrieves data just fine but as it stands my query is:

SELECT Title FROM Scope()

Simply for me to test it's working. How do I refine this to add a where a clause to search only Pages library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're querying multiple Site Collections use `FullTextSQLQuery` since it searches across the farm and if you plan to query Pages Library of a single Site Collection, use `SPSiteDataQuery` instead. I think you might need `SPSiteDataQuery`?

```
    SPSiteDataQuery queryObj = new SPSiteDataQuery();      
    //query Pages libraries
    queryObj.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate='850' />"; 
    queryObj.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='FileRef' />";
    queryObj.Webs = "<Webs Scope='Recursive' />";
    DataTable dt = SPContext.Current.Web.GetSiteData(query);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        //do something else
    }
```

P.S. `FullTextSqlQuery` may not always return the freshest of data but you can reduce the incremental crawl schedule to 15 mins or 30 mins.

**Update:**

Set the QueryText property of your `FullTextSQLQuery` object like this:

```
fullTextSqlQuery.QueryText =
"select title, ContentClass from scope() where (contentclass = 'STS_List_850')";
```

**"STS_List_850": // denotes a Page Library**

Comment: Thanks Falak. For a few reasons, it's been specified that I use a FullTextSQLQuery. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have update my response